# Prevent duplicating aop proxy

Tags: java, spring, aop

I have one ear which has two modules: module1 and module2. Each of the modules has own application context. Both modules in their contexts imports same aop:

```
<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="convertExceptionPointcut"
                  expression="@within(services.annotations.Manager)"/>
    <aop:aspect ref="convertExceptionAdvice" order="100">
        <aop:around method="around" pointcut-ref="convertExceptionPointcut"/>
    </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>

<bean id="convertExceptionAdvice" class="error.ConvertExceptionAdvice"/>
```

The problem is that classes from both modules has in runtime duplicated aop proxy - one comes from module1 aop, second from module2 aop.

My web.xml:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>appContext-module1.xml, appContext-module2.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- JAX-WS servlet -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jaxws-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSSpringServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jaxws-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ws/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Spring just creates one context which imports both appContext-module1.xml and appContext-module2.xml.

When i use in both contexts same beans with same ids then spring when is putting together contexts, imports just one bean - for beans works overriding. 
For aop when i use same ids, it creates two proxies, so aop proxy is doubled. All aops from module1 go also to module2 and all aops from module2 go also to module1.

Is there some way to override also aops, so it's not doubled?

The other solution what i thought could work would be to create two separated contexts for each of the module. Is it possible to define two ContextLoaderListeners in web.xml?

Comment: You can try to give your <aop:aspect ..> definition id attribute to tell Spring it is the same aspect, this shoud work the same way as your other beans with ids. If this works, it is just a quick fix. I am not sure what is your intention of composing your application and what are dependencies between the modules, but it seems to me that there is something odd with your configuration with same beans with same ids in one merged spring context. You should reconsider how to compose your spring configuration.

Comment: I've created a [JIRA issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11731) for this.